Lefalet change corner coordinates or grid
I'm trying to figure out how to change the coordinate grid. Now there is something like this 
My code:
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
        #map { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
        var yx = L.latLng;

        var xy = function(x, y) {
            if (L.Util.isArray(x)) {
                return yx(x[1], x[0]);
            }
            return yx(y, x);
        };

        var bounds = [[0, 0], [16384, 16384]]; // Обновленные границы карты

        var map = L.map("map", {
            attributionControl: false,
            crs: L.CRS.Simple,
            minZoom: -7,
            maxZoom: 2,
            // Исправленные начальные координаты карты
            center: [16384, 0],
            zoom: -3
        });

        var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://mytitlesite.net/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            minZoom: -7,
            maxNativeZoom: 0,
            zoomOffset: 7
        }).addTo(map);
        // Add event listener for left click
        map.on('click', function(e) {
            console.log('Координаты клика:', e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat); // Выводим координаты в консоль
        });
        tiles.getTileUrl = function(coords) {
            if (coords.z === -7) {coords.y += 1}
            if (coords.z === -6) {coords.y += 1}
            if (coords.z === -5) {coords.y += 2}
            if (coords.z === -4) {coords.y += 4}
            if (coords.z === -3) {coords.y += 7}
            if (coords.z === -2) {coords.y += 13}
            if (coords.z === -1) {coords.y += 25}
            if (coords.z ===  0) {coords.y += 50}
            
            return L.TileLayer.prototype.getTileUrl.bind(tiles)(coords);
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds); // Используем новые границы карты

        L.marker(xy(0, 0)).addTo(map) // Создаем маркер в нижнем левом углу карты
                    .bindTooltip("0,0", {permanent:true}); // Подсказка для маркера

        L.marker(xy(16384, 16384)).addTo(map) // Создаем маркер в верхнем правом углу карты
                    .bindTooltip("16384,16384", {permanent:true}); // Подсказка для маркера


        var grid = L.gridLayer({
            attribution: "Debug tilecoord grid",
            minZoom: -10,
            bounds: bounds,
            //tms: true,
        });

        grid.createTile = function (coords) {
            var tile = L.DomUtil.create("div", "tile-coords");
            tile.style.border = "1px solid black";
            tile.style.lineHeight = "256px";
            tile.style.textAlign = "center";
            tile.style.fontSize = "20px";

            var newX = coords.x;
            var newY = bounds[1][1] - coords.y - 1; // Изменен метод расчета координат

            tile.innerHTML = 
                ["x=" + newX, "y=" + newY, "z=" + (coords.z + 7)].join(", ");

            return tile;
        };

        grid.addTo(map);


    </script>
    
</body>

</html>

example from leaflet non-geographical map with tilelayer: the map appears to have a vertical offset?
How can I make the bottom left corner be 0.0 and not in the center of the map border?
And the top right corner is 16384,16384
I got the idea to use something in this format, but I apparently have problems with the borders of the map and because of this the coordinates do not quite match
  var mapWidth = map.getSize().x; // Ширина карты в пикселях
  var mapHeight = map.getSize().y; // Высота карты в пикселях
  var maxCoord = 16384; // Максимальная координата

  // Calculate coordinates based on map size and click location
  var xCoord = Math.round((e.containerPoint.x / mapWidth) * maxCoord);
  var yCoord = Math.round((1 - (e.containerPoint.y / mapHeight)) * maxCoord);

  console.log('Координаты клика:', xCoord, yCoord);
  console.log('Координаты карты:', e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);

On the map from which I base the click coordinates, for example, 6371.00;14832.00, and on my map it is 8784;10806
I have come to this option for now: a sight where the marker should ideally be.

My new code:
    map.on('click', function(e) {
        var maxCoord = 16384;

        // Преобразуем географические координаты клика в пиксели на глобальной карте
        var projectedPoint = map.project(e.latlng, 6); // Используем зум 6 для эталонного преобразования
        var globalPixelX = projectedPoint.x;
        var globalPixelY = projectedPoint.y;

        // Преобразуем глобальные пиксели в координаты вашей системы
        var customX = globalPixelX;
        var customY = globalPixelY;

        // Переводим Y-координаты от верхнего левого угла к нижнему левому углу
        var customYFromBottomLeft = maxCoord - customY;

        // Выводим координаты
        console.log('Ваши координаты от нижнего левого угла:', customX.toFixed(2), customYFromBottomLeft.toFixed(2));
    });
        // Функция для установки маркера по кастомным координатам
function setMarker(maxCoord,customX, customY) {
    // Переводим Y-координаты от нижнего левого угла к верхнему левому углу
    var customYFromTopLeft = maxCoord - customY;

    // Преобразуем кастомные координаты в пиксели на глобальной карте
    var projectedPoint = L.point(customX, customYFromTopLeft);
    
    // Преобразуем пиксели на глобальной карте в географические координаты
    var latlng = map.unproject(projectedPoint, 6); // Используем зум 6 для обратного преобразования
    
    // Создаем маркер с указанными координатами
    var marker = L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);

    // Привязываем всплывающее окно (попап) к маркеру с указанным содержимым
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
}

// Пример использования функции для установки маркера по кастомным координатам
setMarker(16384, 6416.56, 14786.13, "<b>Местоположение</b><br>Широта: 6416.56<br>Долгота: 14786.13");

